# Only output columns with differences Proc Compare

Tags: sas

I have the following code:

```
proc compare base=Old_Data compare=New_Data
out=Comp_Data outnoequal outbase outcomp outdif noprint criterion=0.0001;
id Test_ID;
run;
```

where i have the following datasets:

Old_Data

```
Test_ID  Var1   Var2

0000001  1234   4567

0000002  1111   45
```

New Data

```
Test_ID  Var1   Var2

0000001  1234   4567

0000002  1110   45
```

In the output file i get the following:

```
_TYPE_   _OBS_ Test_ID  Var1   Var2

BASE     2     0000002  1111   45

COMPARE  2     0000002  1110   45

DIF      2     0000002  -1     E
```

When I want to get the following:

```
_TYPE_   _OBS_ Test_ID  Var1

BASE     2     0000002  1111 

COMPARE  2     0000002  1110

DIF      2     0000002  -1
```

How do i get the code to automatically do this rather then me manually checking and then dropping `var2`?

Answer (score 0):

Add data set option `DROP=` to the output data set.

```
proc compare 
    base=Old_Data 
    compare=New_Data
    out=Comp_Data(DROP=VAR2)   /* drop variable from output data set */
    criterion=0.0001
    outnoequal outbase outcomp outdif noprint
;
    id Test_ID;
run;
```